# Vaadin 14 - RichTextEditor - format

Tags: java, vaadin, rich-text-editor, richtextarea

I have been used Vaadin 8 to build applications for reporting purposes. I have used RichTextArea to keep formatted data input from user. There were possible to copy/paste a formatted table into RichTextArea.

I have migrated my application to Vaadin 14 and tried to use RichTextEditor to do the same. I even was decided to purchase Pro subscription, however I was surprised seeing the pasted value from ex. Excel does not format as expected. It appears as a almost plain text.

Is it possible to use the component (or other) and get the expected result?

[Pasted content from Excel 8 (expected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO0xC.png)

[The same content from Excel pasted in Vaadin 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjSxw.png)

Comment: This looks to be missing feature in the library that RTE has been build on https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2573

Comment: Maybe look into other rich text editors? There are handy community integrations for TinyMCE and CKEditor in the https://vaadin.com/directory

Comment: TinyMCE is what I have looked for. Thanks